# Why does uint256 d = a + (a++); give a different answer than uint256 d = (a++) + a;

Tags: solidity

Why does it give a different answer for variable d

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract Exercise{
    uint256 a = 2;
    
    uint256 public c = a + a++; 
    uint256 public d = a + a++; // here why does a + (a++) give 7 but (a++) + a give 6 
    uint public e = a;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because of how `a++` works. It returns a, then increments it. `a + (a++);` equals a + a, and the next time a is going to be accessed, its value will have been incremented, and `(a++) + a` is a + a, but a has been incremented before its value is read the second time. [Heres another question about the ++ operator](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/why-does-i-cost-less-gas-than-i/133164#133164)